# How to Display XML Value

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm really confused here. This is my xml

```
<wpt lat="11.928109300" lon="121.951084200">
  <name>Fuel:Petron</name>
  <cmt>Fuel:Petron</cmt>
  <desc>Fuel:Petron</desc>
</wpt>
```

I can read this part of the xml.

```
<name>Fuel:Petron</name>
<cmt>Fuel:Petron</cmt>
<desc>Fuel:Petron</desc>
```

But this part of the xml is kind of difficult to read.

```
<wpt lat="11.928109300" lon="121.951084200">
```

Comment: What do you mean by "difficult to read"? Do you get an error? Can you show your code?

Comment: it's difficult becuase i don't have any idea how it read that line of code.:D

Comment: Please show the code you are using now.

Comment: 'xr = New XmlDocument'

'xr.Load("Path")'

'datagrid1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value =root.GetElementsByTagName("name").Item(0).InnerText'

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@` to access XML attributes.

**Example:**

```
Dim xml = <wpt lat="11.928109300" lon="121.951084200">
            <name>Fuel:Petron</name>
            <cmt>Fuel:Petron</cmt>
            <desc>Fuel:Petron</desc>
           </wpt>

Console.WriteLine("lat: " & xml.@lat)
Console.WriteLine("lon: " & xml.@lon)
```

**Output:**

```
lat: 11.928109300
lon: 121.951084200
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to work with XML in .NET, it isn't clear which one you're using. I personally prefer [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx), for example :

```
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("path_to_xml_file.xml")
'or use XDocument.Parse() if you have xml string instead of file
'
Console.WriteLine("lat: {0}, lon: {1}", _
                        doc.Root.Attribute("lat").ToString(), _
                        doc.Root.Attribute("lon").ToString())
For Each element As XElement In doc.Elements()
    Console.WriteLine("element name: {0}, value: {1}", _
                        element.Name.LocalName, _
                        element.Value)
Next
```

Another thing, it isn't clear what you mean by "*difficult to read*". Yes it is different because the information provided as attribute value in that particular element, not element's value as in the other 3. But you'll be able to get value from attribute as straightforward as in above example.

Comment: doc.Attribute("lat").ToString(),doc.Attribute("lon").ToString()) does not read any string..

Comment: sorry, should've been `doc.Root.Attribute("lat").ToString()`

Comment: were did you get the Root?

Comment: `XDocument` has `Root` property, in this sample the root points to `<wpt>` element.

Comment: this sample assume that your XML contains only one `<wpt>`, which is the root element. The error is likely because your xml root doesn't have those 2 attributes.